# What is the interval of $A=\frac{2x-6}{x-4}$ provided that $5\lt x\lt 9$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $A=\frac{2x-6}{x-4}$
>
> $5\lt x\lt9$
>
> Find $?\lt A\lt ? $

I tried to solve this problem by trying to get $A$ into an expression that wouldn't have $x$ in the denominator.

I know that I can't just find the intervals of $2x-6$ and $x-4$ and divide these two intervals.

How can I solve this in the simplest way possible?

Comment: While it is not possible to avoid *dividing* by an expression involving $x$, it is possible to rewrite $A$ in a way that will not have $x$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $A=2+\frac 2 {x-4}$. Can you use this to find the range?

Comment: Yes, I can. How did I not see this?! I'm grateful

Comment: @EldarRahimli If you are grateful, you can *accept* this answer by clicking the tick to make it green.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{2x-6}{x-4}$, then show that $f'(x)<0$ for $x \in [5,9]$. Since $f(5)=4$ , $f(9)=\frac{12}{5}$ and $f$ is continuous, we have $f([5,9])=[\frac{12}{5},4]$. Thus

$$f((5,9))=(\frac{12}{5},4).$$